# Do not show console window in release but show in debug

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I would like to create a program that will run in background as a final product. For debug purpose I want it to display a console.

I learned that there is a **ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );** function, but if I use it in a 'standard' main function the console window still pops up for a moment. I was trying to work it out like this (yes I know it's crappy):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>


#define DEBUG
//#undef DEBUG

#ifndef DEBUG
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );    

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
#else
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE")
    int main(int argc, int **argv)
    {
        HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();

        while(1);

        return 0;
    }
#endif
```

Here I managed to prevent the window form popping up, but I can't pass parameters to the program.

I believe there is a much better solution for this. Can you share?

PS

I don't want to use .NET.

Comment: Hm, I'm going to answer this question. Meanwhile, will anyone else who thinks of answering, please note that the behavior has nothing to do with using standard `main` or not. I.e., if you're reading this and thinks so, then please hold your horses.

Comment: I don't get the problem.  Why are you calling GetConsoleWindow() in WinMain?  There is none.  If you don't want to display a window in the Release build then just don't create one.  You don't have to do the hokeypokey with #pragma comment, the project settings for the Debug and the Release configurations are seperate.

Comment: You should consider using DebugView.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647  It will display debugging strings in debug mode only.  Note, since only one debugger can be attached to a running program, it will not work if you are debugging under the IDE.

Comment: Why do you need to display a console for debugging? If you are displaying debug information, you should be logging instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer to the first part of the question, "Here I managed to prevent the window form popping up", i.e. how to set the Windows subsystem for an application in Visual C++.

I will answer the second part of the question, about command line arguments, separately.

```
// How to create a Windows GUI or console subsystem app with a standard `main`.

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   error Hey, this is Visual C++ specific source code!
#endif

// Better set this in the project settings, so that it's more easily configured.
#ifdef  NDEBUG
#   pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:windows /entry:mainCRTStartup" )
#else
#   pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:console" )
#endif

#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  NOMINMAX
#define NOMINAX
#undef  STRICT
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox( 0, L"Hi!", L"This is the app!", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
}
```

The **`NDEBUG`** standard C++ macro is designed for suppressing the effect of standard `assert`, so it’s not required to be globally meaningful. However, in practice it is globally meaningful. And then it provides a bit of portability compared to using a Visual C++ macro such as `DEBUG`.

Anyway, in order to make it easier to configure the subsystem, unless you want to *enforce* that debug builds should be console and release builds should be GUI, then I recommend doing this in the project settings rather than via a `#pragma` (note also that e.g. the g++ compiler does not support linker pragmas, so using the project settings is more portable).

If you want you can check the subsystem programmatically instead of just by inspection (i.e. instead of noting whether the above program produces a console or not):

```
// How to create a Windows GUI or console subsystem app with a standard `main`.

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   error Hey, this is Visual C++ specific source code!
#endif

// Better set this in the project settings, so that it's more easily configured.
#ifdef  NDEBUG
#   pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:windows /entry:mainCRTStartup" )
#else
#   pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:console" )
#endif

#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  NOMINMAX
#define NOMINAX
#undef  STRICT
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>

#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <string>           // std::wstring
#include <sstream>          // std::wostringstream
using namespace std;

template< class Type >
wstring stringFrom( Type const& v )
{
    wostringstream  stream;

    stream << v;
    return stream.str();
}

class S
{
private:
    wstring     s_;

public:
    template< class Type >
    S& operator<<( Type const& v )
    {
        s_ += stringFrom( v );
        return *this;
    }

    operator wstring const& () const { return s_; }
    operator wchar_t const* () const { return s_.c_str(); }
};

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS const& imageHeaderRef()
{
    HMODULE const                   hInstance   =
        GetModuleHandle( nullptr );

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER const* const   pImageHeader    =
        reinterpret_cast< IMAGE_DOS_HEADER const* >( hInstance );
    assert( pImageHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE );     // "MZ"

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS const* const   pNTHeaders      = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS const*>(
            reinterpret_cast< char const* >( pImageHeader ) + pImageHeader->e_lfanew
            );
    assert( pNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC );    // "PE"

    return *pNTHeaders;
}

int main()
{
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS const& imageHeader = imageHeaderRef();
    WORD const              subsystem   = imageHeader.OptionalHeader.Subsystem;

    MessageBox(
        0,
        S() << L"Subsystem " << subsystem << L" "
            << (0?0
                : subsystem == IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI?     L"GUI"
                : subsystem == IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI?     L"Console"
                : L"Other"),
        L"Subsystem info:",
        MB_SETFOREGROUND );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still pass parameters to a regular, non-console Win32 program: they just show up in the single `lpCmdLine` string, all globbed together into one big command line.  You can use [`CommandLineToArgvW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to parse that into separate arguments, but do note that that function is only available in the Unicode flavor.  For example:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    // Common main function (Unicode args)
}

#ifndef DEBUG
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Forward invocation to wmain
    int argc;
    LPWSTR *argv = CommandLineToArgvW(pCmdLine, &argc);
    int status = wmain(argc, argv);
    LocalFree(argv);
    return status;
}
#endif
```

I'd also recommend using your project settings to set the executable's subsystem (console or Windows) depending on the configuration instead of using a `#pragma` to do it.

Comment: Two notes. (1) CommandLineToArgvW [has a silly bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733959/windows-api-commandlinetoargvw-parsing-is-incorrect). (2) if one should avoid Visual C++ specific `#pragma` for setting the Windows subsystem, and instead use the project settings, then for consistency I think one should also avoid using a Visual C++ specific startup function for retrieving Unicode arguments, and instead use the `GetCommandLine` function + proper parsing (thus also avoiding the mentioned bug).

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the second part of the question, “but I can't pass parameters to the program”, i.e. how to obtain the command line arguments in a Visual C++ Windows app.

The simplest but also most limited way is to use the arguments of a standard C++ `main`,

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // Whatever, e.g.
    vector<string> const args( argv, argv + argc );
}
```

The C++ standard strongly suggests that those arguments should be encoded with some *multi-byte character set* such as UTF-8,

**C++11 §3.6.1/2**:

> “If `argc` is nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in `argv[0]`
>   through `argv[argc-1]` as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte strings (NTMBSs) (17.5.2.1.4.2) and `argv[0]` shall be the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the name used to invoke the program or `""`.”

However, at the time of the first C++ standard, in 1998, neither the *nix world convention, nor the Windows convention, was to do this. Instead the convention was to pass the arguments with some locale-specific character encoding. The Linux world almost immediately started a migration towards UTF-8, while Windows did not, so that still as of 2012 in Windows the standard `main` arguments are not sufficient to pass e.g. arbitrary filenames…

Happily, in Windows the **command line** that’s passed to the process, and that is available via the `GetCommandLine` API function, is UTF-16 encoded, which means that any filename (and indeed any text) can be passed.

On the third hand, the API function that provides a standard parsing of the command line, `CommandLineToArgvW`, has [at least one sillybug](http://preview.tinyurl.com/CommandLineToArgvWBug), and maybe more… And presumably the non-standard Visual C++ Unicode C++ startup function `wmain` has arguments provided by that function. So for best results, until that’s been fixed one should use some proper home-brewed command line parsing, e.g. as illustrated in the program below (I just picked an ad-hoc “personal tool” program I made last week, it’s similar to the Windows 2000 Resource Kit’s `timethis`):

```
// A program to measure the execution time of another program.
// Based vaguely on Jeffrey Richter's "timep" program in
// the 2nd edition of "Win32 System Programming".
//
// Author: Alf P. Steinbach, 2012. License: Boost license 1.0.

#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  STRICT
#define STRICT
#undef  NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>            // PathGetCharType

#include    <assert.h>          // assert
#include    <functional>        // std::function
#include    <iomanip>           // set::setfill, std::setw
#include    <iostream>          // std::wcout, std::endl
#include    <sstream>           // std::wostringstream
#include    <stddef.h>          // ptrdiff_t
#include    <stdexcept>         // std::runtime_error, std::exception
#include    <stdint.h>          // int64_t
#include    <string>            // std::string
#include    <type_traits>       // std::is_fundamental
#include    <utility>           // std::move
using namespace std;

#if !defined( CPP_STATIC_ASSERT )
#   define CPP_STATIC_ASSERT( e )   static_assert( e, #e )
#endif

#if !defined( CPP_NORETURN )
#   define CPP_NORETURN             [[noreturn]]
#endif
// MSVC  workaround: "#define CPP_NORETURN __declspec( noreturn )"
// clang workaround: "#define CPP_NORETURN __attribute__(( noreturn ))"

namespace cpp {
    namespace detail {
        template< class Destination, class Source >
        class ImplicitCast
        {
        public:
            static Destination value( Source const v )
            {
                return static_cast<Destination>( v );
            }
        };

        template< class Source >
        class ImplicitCast< bool, Source >
        {
        public:
            static bool value( Source const v )
            {
                return !!v;     // Shuts up Visual C++ sillywarning about performance.
            }
        };
    };

    template< class Destination, class Source >
    Destination implicitCast( Source const v )
    {
        CPP_STATIC_ASSERT( is_fundamental< Destination >::value );
        CPP_STATIC_ASSERT( is_fundamental< Source >::value );

        return detail::ImplicitCast< Destination, Source >::value( v );
    }

    typedef ptrdiff_t       Size;

    inline bool hopefully( bool const c ) { return c; }

    inline CPP_NORETURN bool throwX( string const& s )
    {
        throw runtime_error( s );
    }

    inline CPP_NORETURN bool throwX( string const& s, exception const& reasonX )
    {
        throwX( s + "\n!Because - " + reasonX.what() );
    }

    class ScopeGuard
    {
    private:
        function<void()>  cleanup_;

        ScopeGuard( ScopeGuard const& );                // No such.
        ScopeGuard& operator=( ScopeGuard const& );     // No such.

    public:
        ~ScopeGuard() { cleanup_(); }

        ScopeGuard( function<void()> const cleanup )
            : cleanup_( cleanup )
        {}
    };

    class SubstringRef
    {
    private:
        wchar_t const*  start_;
        wchar_t const*  end_;

    public:
        Size length() const             { return end_ - start_; }
        wchar_t const* start() const    { return start_; }
        wchar_t const* end() const      { return end_; }

        SubstringRef( wchar_t const* start, wchar_t const* end )
            : start_( start )
            , end_( end )
        {}
    };

    inline void skipWhitespace( wchar_t const*& p )
    {
        while( *p != L'\0' && iswspace( *p ) ) { ++p; }
    }

    inline wchar_t const* theAfterWhitespacePart( wchar_t const* p )
    {
        skipWhitespace( p );
        return p;
    }

    inline void invert( bool& b ) { b = !b; }
}  // namespace cpp

namespace winapi {
    using cpp::hopefully;
    using cpp::invert;
    using cpp::Size;
    using cpp::skipWhitespace;
    using cpp::SubstringRef;
    using cpp::theAfterWhitespacePart;
    using cpp::throwX;

    namespace raw {
        typedef DWORD                   DWord;
        typedef FILETIME                FileTime;
        typedef HANDLE                  Handle;
        typedef PROCESS_INFORMATION     ProcessInformation;
        typedef SYSTEMTIME              SystemTime;
        typedef WORD                    Word;
    }  // namespace raw

    // The following logic is mainly a workaround for a bug in CommandLineToArgvW.
    // See [http://preview.tinyurl.com/CommandLineToArgvWBug].
    inline SubstringRef nextArgumentIn( wchar_t const* const commandLine )
    {
        wchar_t const*  p   = commandLine;

        skipWhitespace( p );
        wchar_t const* const    start   = p;

        bool isInQuotedPart = false;
        while( *p != L'\0' && (isInQuotedPart || !iswspace( *p ) ) )
        {
            if( *p == L'\"' ) { invert( isInQuotedPart ); }
            ++p;
        }
        return SubstringRef( start, p );
    }

    // This corresponds essentially to the argument of wWinMain(...).
    inline wchar_t const* commandLineArgPart()
    {
        SubstringRef const programSpec = nextArgumentIn( GetCommandLine() );
        return theAfterWhitespacePart( programSpec.end() );
    }

    class ProcessInfo
    {
    private:
        raw::ProcessInformation info_;

        ProcessInfo( ProcessInfo const& );              // No such.
        ProcessInfo& operator=( ProcessInfo const& );   // No such.

    public:
        raw::ProcessInformation& raw()      { return info_; }
        raw::Handle handle() const          { return info_.hProcess; }

        ~ProcessInfo()
        {
            ::CloseHandle( info_.hThread );
            ::CloseHandle( info_.hProcess );
        }

        ProcessInfo(): info_() {}

        ProcessInfo( ProcessInfo&& other )
            : info_( move( other.info_ ) )
        {
            other.info_ = raw::ProcessInformation();      // Zero.
        }
    };

    inline ProcessInfo createProcess( wchar_t const commandLine[] )
    {
        STARTUPINFO         startupInfo     = { sizeof( startupInfo ) };
        ProcessInfo         processInfo;
        wstring             mutableCommandLine( commandLine );

        mutableCommandLine += L'\0';
        GetStartupInfo( &startupInfo );
        bool const  creationSucceeded = !!CreateProcess (
            nullptr,                // LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
            &mutableCommandLine[0], // LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
            nullptr,                // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            nullptr,                // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
            true,                   // BOOL bInheritHandles,
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,  // DWORD dwCreationFlags,
            nullptr,                // LPVOID lpEnvironment,
            nullptr,                // LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
            &startupInfo,           // LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            &processInfo.raw()      // LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
            );
        hopefully( creationSucceeded )
            || throwX( "winapi::createProcess: CreateProcess failed" );
        return processInfo;
    }

    inline raw::Handle dup(
        raw::Handle const       h,
        raw::DWord const        desiredAccess,
        bool                    inheritable = false
        )
    {
        raw::Handle result  = 0;
        bool const wasDuplicated = !!DuplicateHandle(
            GetCurrentProcess(), h,
            GetCurrentProcess(), &result,
            desiredAccess,
            inheritable,
            0               // options
            );
        hopefully( wasDuplicated )
            || throwX( "winapi::dup: DuplicateHandle failed" );
        assert( result != 0 );
        return result;
    }

    inline int64_t mSecsFromRelative( raw::FileTime const t )
    {
        ULARGE_INTEGER  asLargeInt;

        asLargeInt.u.HighPart   = t.dwHighDateTime;
        asLargeInt.u.LowPart    = t.dwLowDateTime;

        return asLargeInt.QuadPart/10000;
    }

    SubstringRef filenamePart( SubstringRef const& path )
    {
        wchar_t const*  p     = path.end();

        while( p != path.start() && PathGetCharType( *p ) != GCT_SEPARATOR )
        {
            --p;
        }
        if( PathGetCharType( *p ) == GCT_SEPARATOR ) { ++p; }
        return SubstringRef( p, path.end() );
    }
}  // namespace winapi

winapi::ProcessInfo createProcess( wchar_t const commandLine[], char const errMsg[] )
{
    try{ return winapi::createProcess( commandLine ); }
    catch( exception const& x ) { cpp::throwX( errMsg, x ); }
}

winapi::raw::Handle run( wchar_t const commandLine[] )
{
    namespace raw = winapi::raw;
    using cpp::hopefully;
    using cpp::throwX;
    using winapi::dup;
    using winapi::ProcessInfo;

    static char const* const createErrMsg = "Failed to create process";
    ProcessInfo const process = createProcess( commandLine, createErrMsg );

    // Early handle duplication ensures that one has the required rights.
    raw::Handle const   accessibleHandle    =
        dup( process.handle(), PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | SYNCHRONIZE );

    raw::DWord const waitResult = WaitForSingleObject( process.handle(), INFINITE );
    hopefully( waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
        || throwX( "Failed waiting for process termination." );

    return accessibleHandle;
}

class Interval
{
private:
    int     hours_;
    int     minutes_;
    int     seconds_;
    int     milliseconds_;

public:
    int msecs() const       { return milliseconds_; }
    int seconds() const     { return seconds_; }
    int minutes() const     { return minutes_; }
    int hours() const       { return hours_; }

    Interval( int msecs, int seconds = 0, int minutes = 0, int hours = 0 )
        : milliseconds_( msecs )
        , seconds_( seconds )
        , minutes_( minutes )
        , hours_( hours )
    {
        assert( unsigned( hours ) < 24 );
        assert( unsigned( minutes ) < 60 );
        assert( unsigned( seconds ) < 60 );
        assert( unsigned( msecs ) < 1000 );
    }

    static Interval fromMSecs( int msecs )
    {
        int const   totalSeconds    = msecs / 1000;
        int const   totalMinutes    = totalSeconds / 60;
        int const   totalHours      = totalMinutes / 24;

        return Interval(
            msecs % 1000, totalSeconds % 60, totalMinutes %60, totalHours
            );
    }
};

wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, Interval const& t )
{
    wostringstream  formatter;

    formatter << setfill( L'0' );
    formatter
        << setw( 2 ) << t.hours() << ":"
        << setw( 2 ) << t.minutes() << ":"
        << setw( 2 ) << t.seconds() << "."
        << setw( 3 ) << t.msecs();
    return (stream << formatter.str());
}

string narrowStringFrom( cpp::SubstringRef const& s )
{
    return string( s.start(), s.end() );    // Non-ANSI characters => garbage.
}

void cppMain()
{
    namespace raw = winapi::raw;
    using cpp::hopefully;
    using cpp::implicitCast;
    using cpp::ScopeGuard;
    using cpp::SubstringRef;
    using cpp::throwX;
    using winapi::commandLineArgPart;
    using winapi::filenamePart;
    using winapi::mSecsFromRelative;
    using winapi::nextArgumentIn;

    SubstringRef const      programSpec         = nextArgumentIn( GetCommandLine() );
    SubstringRef const      programName         = filenamePart( programSpec );
    wchar_t const* const    otherCommandLine    = commandLineArgPart();

    hopefully( nextArgumentIn( otherCommandLine ).length() > 0 )
        || throwX( "Usage: " + narrowStringFrom( programName ) + " command" );

    raw::DWord const    startMSecs          = GetTickCount(); 
    raw::Handle const   finishedProcess     = run( otherCommandLine );
    raw::DWord const    endMSecs            = GetTickCount();
    raw::DWord const    realElapsedMSecs    = endMSecs - startMSecs;
    ScopeGuard const    closingHandle( [=]() { CloseHandle( finishedProcess ); } );

    Interval const      realElapsedTime = Interval::fromMSecs( realElapsedMSecs );

    static char const* const    commandLineLabel    = "Command line: ";
    static char const* const    rElapsedTimeLabel   = "External elapsed time:   ";
    static char const* const    pElapsedTimeLabel   = "In-process elapsed time: ";
    static char const* const    kernelTimeLabel     = "In-process kernel time:  ";
    static char const* const    userTimeLabel       = "In-process user time:    ";

    wclog << endl;
    wclog << commandLineLabel << "[" << otherCommandLine << "]" << endl;
    wclog << rElapsedTimeLabel << realElapsedTime << endl;

    raw::FileTime   creationTime;
    raw::FileTime   exitTime;
    raw::FileTime   kernelTime;
    raw::FileTime   userTime;
    bool const  timesWereObtained = !!GetProcessTimes(
        finishedProcess, &creationTime, &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime
        );
    hopefully( timesWereObtained )
        || throwX( "cppMain: GetProcessTimes failed" );

    int const   elapsedTimeMSecs= implicitCast<int>(
        mSecsFromRelative( exitTime ) - mSecsFromRelative( creationTime )
        );
    int const   kernelTimeMSecs = implicitCast<int>( mSecsFromRelative( kernelTime ) );
    int const   userTimeMSecs   = implicitCast<int>( mSecsFromRelative( userTime ) );

    wclog << pElapsedTimeLabel << Interval::fromMSecs( elapsedTimeMSecs ) << endl;
    wclog << kernelTimeLabel << Interval::fromMSecs( kernelTimeMSecs ) << endl;
    wclog << userTimeLabel << Interval::fromMSecs( userTimeMSecs ) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        wcerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing your subsystem mode depending on the build type, consider using [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to explicitly create a console for your process.